# What does this syntax mean in C? variable = (arg0 + arg1 == arg2 ? 0x1 : 0x0) & 0xff;

Tags: c

I usually work in Java and I was given some C code, I am not finding this in any documentation -- it probably doesn't help that I'm not sure what it should be doing so I don't know where in documentation to look!

```
variable = (arg0 + arg1 == arg2 ? 0x1 : 0x0) & 0xff;
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand with this statement?

Comment: Research "ternary operator".

Comment: Java has an exact same syntax. Bad excuse..

Comment: The `& 0xff` is redundant, because `variable` will be set to `1` or `0`. So that might be confusing the issue.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm still learning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the mask with `0xff` and the ternary operator are redundant.

The first operation `arg0 + arg1 == arg2` is a simple comparison.

C does not have boolean types for the comparison operators, the result is of type `int` and its value is either `0` for false or `1` for true.

The ternary operator, almost the same as Java's, is redundant as it evaluates as `0x1` for non `0` and `0x0` for `0`.

The bitwise mask operator `&` is also redundant because `0 & 0xff` is `0` and `1 & 0xff` is `1`.

Overall, this expression simplifies to just `variable = (arg0 + arg1 == arg2);`  which can be written more explicitly as

```
if (arg0 + arg1 == arg2)
    variable = 1;
else
    variable = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`arg0 + arg1 == arg2 ? 0x1 : 0x0` means `0x1` if `arg0 + arg1 == arg2` is `true` and `0x0` if `arg0 + arg1 == arg2` is `false`.

Everything else is same as Java.

?: is a quick if/then/else operator called Ternary, as others have mentioned.

Comment: Everything is same as Java.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Thanks, I don't work much with Java so I didn't remember it also has the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

1. `arg0 + arg1` is compared with `arg2` if it is true output is `0x1` else `0X0`. Then bitwise `and` operation is done between the result and `0xff`.

bitwise and with 0xff result in same value, i.e.

```
a & 0xff = a;
```

Ternary conditional

```
a ? b : c
```

if a is true then result is b else c.

Comment: @Roushan45 That is understandable i guess.

Comment: can u go for some code snippet if u don't mind with o/p